# Cable Box and computer sharing TV?

Tags: networking

I'm setting up a system in my house whereby a thin client computer and our cable box share the TV. Plan is to be able to watch either cable TV or something from our very large media collection stored on a 6 TB drive connected to the thin client. I have the cable box hooked up to HMDI 1 and it has been working for over a year.

The thin client is connected to the Internet so I can download purchased media easily using a wireless keyboard onto my storage drive. It is a new addition, and when I plug it in to HDMI 2, the signal from cable TV becomes intermittent, even when the thin client is not powered up.

Is this some proprietary security thing the cable company has in place? Strangely, I have had an Amazon firestick connected through HDMI 2 previously and did not witness this issue. I have Spectrum cable. Cable box and thin client both sit in a media cabinet across the room from the TV and HDMI cables run in the attic.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Especially since you are writhing in a block, it's really hard to read

Comment: Sorry. I have  TV with 2 HDMI ports. Cable Box is in HDMI 1. Problem is that when mini computer is plugged into HDMI 2, cable signal becomes intermittent, even though mini computer is off. Thoughts as to why and possible solutions?

Comment: Have you tried a different HDMI cable preferably one certified for HDMI 2.0 even if your devices are not capable.